# How to prove that $\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \geq f(\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n))$

Tags: calculus, inequality, continuity, limsup-and-liminf

We were given HW where it is asked to prove that, $\limsup_{n \rightarrow\infty} f(x_n) \geq f(\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n))$, for any bounded sequence $\{x_n\}$ and continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Could anyone give me a direction?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of [limit superior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior)? What do you already know about it? Several equivalent definitions are used: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{k\ge n} x_k$, largest cluster point, largest limit of a subsequence, and another definition using $\varepsilon$'s.

Comment: the definition is $limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n=inf \{sup_{m>n,{n \rightarrow \infty}\{ x_n \}}\}$

Answer (score 5):

We are given two inputs: $x_{n}$ is a bounded sequence which means that $\limsup x_{n} = a$ is finite and the fact that $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous. Since $x_{n}$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous the sequence $f(x_{n})$ is also bounded and hence $\limsup f(x_{n}) = A$ exists and is finite. We need to prove that $A \geq f(a)$.

We establish this by contradiction. Let us assume $A < f(a)$ and see where we are led to. Also let $2\epsilon = f(a) - A > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $a$ we know that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - a| < \delta$. Since $a = \limsup x_{n}$ we know that $x_{n} < a + \delta$ for all sufficiently large values of $n$ and $x_{n} > a - \delta$ for infinitely many values of $n$. Hence there are infinitely many values of $x_{n}$ such that $|x_{n} - a| < \delta$ and hence for these values of $x_{n}$ we have $|f(x_{n}) - f(a)| < \epsilon$. Thus there are infinitely many values of $x_{n}$ for which $$f(a) - \epsilon < f(x_{n}) < f(a) + \epsilon$$ Now consider the fact that $A = \limsup f(x_{n})$ which implies that "$f(x_{n}) < A + \epsilon = f(a) - \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large values of $n$" and this clearly contradicts the previous inequality "$f(a) - \epsilon < f(x_{n})$ for infinitely many values of $n$"

We have the reached the contradiction needed for our goal. This means that $A \geq f(a)$.

**Update**: By the way this is a very good question (at least for me). I was aware of the fact that "continuity preserves limit operation" but never bothered to check how continuity impacts the limit superior and limit inferior. The proof above has enlightened me that continuity does not preserve $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ but rather gives them a different twist. +1 for OP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but something is bothering me. I have a problem with your statement that "Since $x_{n}$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous the sequence $f(x_{n})$ is also bounded". For example take $\{x_n\}=\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then, $x_{n}$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous but the sequence $f(x_{n})$ is not bounded.. am I missing something?

Comment: @user83081: I suppose you miss the point that $f$ is continuous on whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user83081: I provide further justification of my claim. Since the sequence $x_{n}$ is bounded, we have $x_{n} \in [m, M]$ for all $n$ where $m, M$ are some bounds. Now we know that $f$ is continuous on $[m, M]$ and hence has a minimum value $m_{f}$ and a maximum value $M_{f}$ in interval $[m, M]$ i.e. $f(x) \in [m_{f}, M_{f}]$ for all $x \in [m, M]$. Thus $f(x_{n}) \in [m_{f}, M_{f}]$ for all $n$ and hence sequence $f(x_{n})$ is bounded.

Comment: Why isn't $A=f(a)$ always ?

Comment: @GinKin: I believe the case $A = f(a)$ would occur only when $x_{n} \to a$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

1. Show that if $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$ then there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k} = x$.
2. What can you say about $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f(x_{n_k})$ based on the continuity of $f$?
3. Compare $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f(x_{n_k})$ and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_{n})$.

Comment: I think I do.. Can I say that $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = f(lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_{n_k})$?

Comment: Yes, a function $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous if and only if $a_k\to a$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(a_k)\to f(a)$ holds for each sequence.

Comment: Aren't they always equal in 3 ? (they're probably not but why?)

Comment: @GinKin Consider $f(x)=-x$ and $x_n=(-1)^n$. Then $\limsup x_n=1$ and $\limsup f(x_n)=1 > f(\limsup x_n)=f(1)=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by showing contradiction, 
let us denote $f^* = \limsup f(x_n)$ and $s^* = \limsup (x_n)$, and $f(s^*) = f(\limsup(x_n))$

now $f^*$ is the supremum of subsequential limit of $\{f(x_n)\}$ and $f(s^*)$ belongs to the set of subsequential limit of $\{f(x_n)\}$,( since f is continuous and corresponds to the subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ which converges to $s^*$ )

hence $f^* \ge f(s^*)$ (otherwise $f^*$ is not a supremum)

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$ please.

Answer (score 0):

you can start by showing that if $x$ is an accumulation point of $\{x_n\}$, then, $f(x)$ is an accumulation point of $\{f(x_n) \}$.

Comment: We were not given the definition of accumulation point in class..

Comment: ok so you can just use that there is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k} \}$ that converges to $\lim \sup \{x_n \}$.